# WebStorm - How to edit Jasmine code completion snippets

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, webstorm

When writing Jasmine unit tests in WebStorm (11.0.2), using the Command + N (OS X) command gives me the following popup menu:

Generate

- Jasmine Suite
- Jasmine Spec
- Jasmine beforeEach
- Jasmine afterEach

I'd like to modify the code these menu items generate. For example, I'm using ES6, and would like to change the Jasmine Suite option to generate:

```
describe('suite name', () => {
});
```

Instead of:

```
describe('suite name', function () {
});
```

I'm digging through the WebStorm Preferences, but can't see any options to modify this. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, I know this is old, but did you ever work this out?
Mine's suddenly decided to do double quotes instead of single, and I'd like to switch it back for consistency with the rest of the code base

Comment: @James See my new answer below about using a Live Template.

Comment: Thanks, strangely my switched back.  I haven't experimented yet, but I'm wondering if PHPStorm recognised the rest of the file was using single quotes.  Which would mean it would try and use double quotes on new files.  Don't know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still haven't found a way to edit the code template when using Command-N keyboard shortcut, but similar functionality can be found using a "Live Template", giving you complete control of the template.

Navigate to:

> Preferences -> Editor -> Live Templates

Select the JavaScript option in the right pane, and then the + icon to add a template.

Configuration Values:

**Abbreviation**: desc

**Description**: Jasmine Suite

**Template Text**:

```
describe('$SUITE_DESC$', () => {
  $END$
});
```

Typing 'desc' then Tab, will generate the template. From there, you can add additional live templates for 'it', 'beforeEach' and 'afterEach', using the same approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should change it the file templates settings.

Assuming you are using OSX:

> preferences-->Editor-->File and Code Templates

You will see those list of templates. Pick the template you want to change and edit it.

Comment: I see the file templates at that location, but that doesn't have what I'm looking for. It would make sense if it was a code template, but when navigating to the Code tab, it shows the message "Nothing to show".

Comment: you can add a file template and use a custom template if you don't find any.

Comment: But this isn't used as a file template. These are code templates used multiple times within a single test file.